# How come プレイガイド means "Ticket agency" and not "playguide"?

Tags: etymology, katakana

I've come across プレイガイド and I thought it meant "playguide" (which can be found is *some* dictionaries), but it didn't make sense in its context. I looked it up and found it meant "ticket agency".

How did it come to this? I can't find a link. Phonetically it obviously comes from "playguide", but I can't find a way for it to slide that much to mean what it means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>That's a product name. Basically a ticket vending machine placed at some convenience stores in Japan.</s>

Edit: It's actually a 和製英語 (Japanese-made English word), which probably intended to refer "a place where you can buy ticket for you to 'play'". It generally refers to a ticket store (vending machine, now) that sells tickets for concerts, amusement parks, etc.

Another example of wasei-eigo: Salaryman, Skinship..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasei-eigo
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89

Comment: So it's a [genericized trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark)? I feel like there are a lot of those in Japanese.

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong actually. The wikipedia entry actually says it's 和製英語, wacky Japanese-made English word. 

So it doesn't actually refer to a specific trademark.

Comment: It is NOT a product name.  Why so many upvotes here?

Comment: サラリーマン does not appear to be true 和製英語: instead, this derived from English _"salaried man"_, a phrase appearing in print since at least 1828.